# Implementation of the Algolia search method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, search, algolia

I'm currently developing a mobile application under flutter where I need to search data stored in a Firestore collection via Flutter. I'm currently using Algolia but it doesn't search what I'm asking it to. After several hours of looking at the code, I could not find the error. I have initialized everything correctly. When I print the data from my flutter search, I get the desired data from my Firebase collection from Algolia. The problem is that the data does not want to be displayed in my application.

**Algolia initialization class :**

```
import 'package:algolia/algolia.dart';

class AlgoliaInit {
  static const Algolia algolia = Algolia.init(
    applicationId: "ID",
    apiKey: "APIKEY"
  );
}
```

**Algolia data search method from a text field value :**

```
// *-*-*-*-*-*-*-* Algolia *-*-*-*-*-*-*-* //
    final Algolia algoliaApp = AlgoliaInitialisation.algolia;

      // *-*-*-*-*-*-*-* Research method *-*-*-*-*-*-*-* //
      Future<List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot>> researchAlgoliaMethod(String searchValue) async {
        AlgoliaQuery query = algoliaApp.instance.index("collection").query(searchValue);
        AlgoliaQuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.getObjects();
        List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot> resultats = querySnapshot.hits;
        print(resultats);
        return resultats;
      }
```

**Display of the data retrieved from the application.

The data is being loaded, but is not displayed. The application displays "The data is being loaded..." at the "!snapshot.hasData" level. I don't know why, knowing that the data are correctly retrieved.**

```
StreamBuilder<List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot>>(
                  stream: Stream.fromFuture(researchAlgoliaMethod(searchValue)),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    switch (_source.keys.toList()[0]) {
                      case ConnectivityResult.wifi: case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
                        if(!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return FadeIn(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "The data is being loaded...",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: colorTweenAnimation.value,
                                  fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.0237
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        } else {
                          if(snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                            return FadeIn(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "No furniture with the keyword $searchValue was found.",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor,
                                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.0237
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          } else {
                            List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot> currentResearch = snapshot.requireData;
                            return ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: currentResearch.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.0237,
                                    ),
                                    FadeIn(
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          Get.toNamed("Route1", arguments: GetDataDocuments(docID: currentResearch[index].objectID.toString()));
                                        },
                                        child: Container(
                                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.102,
                                          width: double.maxFinite,
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.096
                                          ),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio / 0.16),
                                            boxShadow: [
                                              BoxShadow(
                                                offset: Offset(
                                                  0,
                                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.006
                                                ),
                                                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.15),
                                                blurRadius: 4,
                                                blurStyle: BlurStyle.normal
                                              ),
                                            ]
                                          ),
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                currentResearch[index].data['field'],
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.0237,
                                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Icon(
                                                FontAwesomeIcons.chevronRight,
                                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                                size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.026
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          }
                        }
                      case ConnectivityResult.none:
                      return FadeIn(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.mobiledata_off_rounded,
                            color: colorTweenAnimation.value,
                            size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.09,
                          ),
                        )
                      );
                    }
                    return Container();
                  }
                )
```

**Example of the printout of the recovered data :**

```
flutter: [{path: collectionName/QNXq--1gKJr---GyEJVL, field_name: Test, objectID: QNXq--1gKJr---GyEJVL, _highlightResult: {path: {value: collectionName/QNXq--1gKJr---GyEJVL, matchLevel: none, matchedWords: []}, field_name: {value: <em>Test</em>, matchLevel: full, fullyHighlighted: true, matchedWords: [test]}}}]
```

**thank you for your help**